Why spdlog not print in async function
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
import spdlog as spd
import asyncio
import logging

async def A():
    asyncio.create_task(B())
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def B():
    logger = spd.DailyLogger(name = 'B', filename = 'B.log', hour = 0, minute = 0, async_mode=True)
    logger.set_level(spd.LogLevel.INFO)
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='B.log', filemode='w')
    # logger = logging.getLogger('B')
    while True:
        logger.info('B')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(A())

First, I created a task B inside A, which prints a line of B every second. When I used Python's default logging, everything worked fine, but with C++'s spdlog, there’s no output, regardless of whether I enable async_mode or not.
I have tried to disable async_mode, still the same

By default spdlog doesn't flush for INFO messages, which is why you don't see anything. It will either flush when it gets enough messages (run your program for a long time or change the sleep interval to 0.01 to see that effect), or periodically (though the Python wrapper for spdlog doesn't seem to support changing this setting), or if you change the setting after which types of messages it should flush:
logger.flush_on(spd.LogLevel.INFO)

(Directly after the .set_level() call.)

Thanks, it worked. Will logger.flush_on(spd.LogLevel.INFO) affect spd logger performance?

To an extent, yes, because every flush costs time (waiting until the OS has written the message to disk), and if you have a lot of log messages, this is maybe not ideal. That said, you are already using the async mode of spdlog, which will cause logging to happen in a background thread, so the time it takes to call logger.info('B') shouldn't change much at all, it's just that spdlog is still working in the background while your other Python code continues. If you are writing a reasonable amount of log messages, I don't think this will be a problem, but it's up to you to test this yourself.
